# Фильтрация на сайте администратора django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-filter

Нужно отфильтровать пользователей, чтобы в выборе поля "owner" были только пользователи из группы "Техническая поддержка". Перерыл гугл ничего подобного не нашел. Прошу сильно не ругаться, я еще новичок)

models.py

```
class Application(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('in_the_work', 'В работе'),
        ('new', 'Новая'),
        ('completed', 'Завершена')
    )

author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = '+')
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
text = models.TextField()
room = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default = datetime.datetime.now)
status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='new')
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = '+', null = True, blank = True)

class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ("can_add_change", "Добавлять и изменять"),
        ("can_close", "Закрывать"),
        ("can_assign", "Назначать"),
    )

def publish(self):
    self.publish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

admin.py

```
class ApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #Разделение по полям(Название, автор и т.п.)
    list_display = ( 'title', 'room', 'published_date', 'status')
    #Добавляет область фильтрации на сайт администрации
    list_filter = ('status', 'published_date', 'author')
    #Поиск
    search_fields = ('title', 'text')
    #Измененный способ выбора автора при написание поста
    raw_id_fields = ('owner',)
    #Фильтрация по дате публикации
    date_hierarchy = 'published_date'
    ordering = ['status', 'published_date']

admin.site.register(Application, ApplicationAdmin)
```

Заранее спасибо!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поможет параметр [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = '+', null = True, blank = True,
                          limit_choices_to={ 'groups__name': 'Техническая поддержка' })
```